# How do I call alert window by click on list item element?

Tags: javascript, events, onclick

Could anyone please assist me with my simple script? I have a list of colors in html code and just need to make my js code to popup an alert with the clicked list item value. Please help me! Here is what I have:

**HTML**

```
<ul id="mylist">
  <li>White </li>
  <li>Silver </li>
  <li>Dark Gray</li>
  <li>Khaki </li>
</ul>
```

And here is JS code (it is displaying an alert with the list item value on window load but i need it to show up after clicking on each item)

```
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
  var a = document.getElementById('mylist').document.getElementsByTagName('li');
  var b=[];
  for(i=0;i<a.length;i++)
  {
    b=a[i].innerText;
    alert(b);
  } 
//-->
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
document.getElementById('mylist').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if ('LI' != event.target.tagName) return;
  alert(event.target.innerText);
}, false);
```

See also:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.target
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener

Answer (score 3):

```
var a = document.getElementById('mylist').getElementsByTagName('li');

for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
      a[i].onclick = function(){
            alert(this.innerHTML);
      }
}
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/ayefap/2/

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot for your help! I am compleltely new to javascripting. Could you please eaxplain about 'this' that you called in the alert?

Comment: @user976813 `this` refers to the object itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = document.getElementById('mylist').getElementsByTagName('li');
```

`document.getElementById("myList")` doesn't have a `.document`

If you use firebug or chrome console you'll get this error there.

Answer (score 0):

Without getting into hooking up click handlers in raw JavaScript, you can do this:

```
<li><a href="javascript://" onclick="alertMe(this)">White</a></li>
```

JS:

```
function alertMe(element) {
      alert(element.innerText)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul id="mylist">

    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="clickMe(this)">White</a></li>
        <li>Silver </li>
            <li>Dark Gray</li>
                <li>Khaki </li>
</ul>
```

Add this to your head section:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function clickMe(cid){
alert(cid.innerHTML);

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $("button").click(function()
  {
    $("li").each(function()
    {
      alert($(this).text());
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>MILK</li>
  <li>CHOCOLATE</li>
  <li>BREAD</li>
</ul>
<button>Click to Alert</button>
```